# PHP Define Object Type to hold MySQL Table Data?

Tags: php, mysql

I am basically trying to retrieve a row from my MySql Database and store the row data in a single Object and pass it to my view. I don't need an array, instead I need to store it as a custom data object named 'User'.

This is what i have so far:

```
public function GetUserData(){

    $this->load->database();
    $query = $this->db->query('SELECT * from eyebase.UserTable WHERE id=1');

    //I have already implemented an array. I need to replace this with an object
    $users= array();
    foreach ($query->result() as $row)
    {
           $users[] = $row;
    }

    //I need to replace the line below with the object I created, instead of the array
    return $users;
}

//This is the object I need to use
class User{
     public $id;
     public $name;
     public $description;
     public $picture;
}
```

Quite simply, just store the row's column values (such as id, Name, Description, Picture) in an object and return it instead of storing them in an array like I have already implemented. How do I do this?